# Spy dependencies with Mockito

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I have a bit of mess with Mockito and fields annotated with @Spy .

I want to test this class:

```
@Service
public class CategoryServiceImpl implements CategoryService {

    @Autowire
    private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    private BoundMapperFacade<CategoryDTO, Category> boundMapper;

    @Autowired
    public void createMapper(final Mapper mapper) {

        boundMapper = mapper.getMapperFactory().getMapperFacade(
                CategoryDTO.class, Category.class);
    }

    // Rest of methods...
}
```

So, I have created a testing class as shown below:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CategoryServiceImplTest {

    @Mock    
    private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    @Spy
    private Mapper mapper;

    @Spy
    private BoundMapperFacade<CategoryDTO, Category> boundMapper;

    @InjectMocks
    private CategoryServiceImpl categoryServiceImpl;    

    // Rest of methods...
}
```

When Mockito instances categoryServiceImpl injects categoryRepository as a mock class but it does not know how to create boundMapper. This class depends on mapper, so I have rewritten my code:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CategoryServiceImplTest {

    @Mock    
    private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    @Spy
    private Mapper mapper;

    private BoundMapperFacade<CategoryDTO, Category> boundMapper = spy(mapper.getMapperFactory().getMapperFacade(
                CategoryDTO.class, Category.class));

    @InjectMocks
    private CategoryServiceImpl categoryServiceImpl;    

    // Rest of methods...
}
```

But now the problem is the creation of boundMapper is executed before Mockito injects mapper, so I get a NullPointerException.

So, is there any way to create an spy class who depends on another one and finally inject this last one in a field tagged as @InjectMocks?

Comment: Why do you want to spy on a Mapper object? The direct dependency of yout class is BoundMapperFacade. That's what you should stub/mock/spy.

Comment: Because boundMapper depends on mapper. You need it to instance the first one. Take a look at createMapper method on CategoryServiceImpl  class

Comment: you could simply add a setup method with an @Before where you call the create method with the spy that you already have i.e. categoryServiceImpl.createMapper(boundMapper);

Answer (score 0):

If you have a spy that depends on a mock or a spy, the only way I've seen to do it is inside the `@Before` decorated function.

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CategoryServiceImplTest {

    @Mock    
    private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    @Spy
    private Mapper mapper;

    private BoundMapperFacade<CategoryDTO, Category> boundMapper = ;

    @InjectMocks
    private CategoryServiceImpl categoryServiceImpl;   

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        boundMapper = spy(mapper
                            .getMapperFactory()
                            .getMapperFacade(CategoryDTO.class, Category.class)
                         );
    }

    // Rest of methods...
}
```

I'm not sure how this works with `@InjectMocks`, so that might be something to look into. There might be a non-decorator version of it that you can run after `boundMapper` is initialized if `CategoryServiceImpl` is dependent on it.